# Querying a dataframe using tkinter checkbox

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I'm very new to python and especially Tkinter.

I want to build a GUI to pick rows from a panda dataframe. I've built the GUI and the row search tool, but can't link them together. The dataframe is a column of months and a column of numbers. (Months can be repeated.) I want to click `January' on the GUI and get the sum of the January numbers.

I imported the dataframe as df before running the following code.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

listbox_frame=Frame(root,borderwidth=5, relief=SUNKEN)
listbox_frame.pack(pady=12)
 
listbox=Listbox(listbox_frame, height=12)
listbox.pack()

listbox.insert(END,"January")
 
for item in ["February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]:
    listbox.insert(END, item)
 
def list_item_selected():
    selection=listbox.curselection()
    if selection:
        print(listbox.get(selection[0]))
 
list_box_button = Button(listbox_frame,text='Select Month', command=list_item_selected)
list_box_button.pack()

root.mainloop()

df.loc[(df['Month'] == list_item_selected), ['Amount']].sum()
```

I didn't include the dataframe in the above. A dummy head looks like this:

```
     Month     Amount
0   January      1
1   January      1
2   January      1  
3   February     2
4   February     2
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Include an overview of the dataframe.

Comment: There is no dataframe in your code.